# Why in any installation prompt (Y/n) the 'Y' is in Uppercase and the 'n' in lowercase?

Tags: command-line

The question itself is self explanatory. As another query I would like to know if it's possible to replace the 'Y' option with 'Enter' keystroke.

Comment: I am sorry, I couldn't find it in the suggestions below. I wouldn't ask if I had seen it in the first place.

Comment: It's not a crime to ask a duplicate question :) Many times duplicates serve an important role in the Stack Exchange network, they work as signposts.

Comment: Oh! Glad to know that!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Generally the capitalized letter means it's the default. If you press enter without typing any letter it will use the default (in this case 'Y').

Comment: do you know if using the 'Y' in lowercase makes a difference?  When I come upon this situation I just hit 'y' and 'enter'.  Just wondering if I am wasting my time hitting 'y', and should just hit 'enter'.  Would it do anything to use 'Y' instead, is 'Y' and 'y' the same in this case?

Comment: Assuming 'y' is the default (in which case it will be capitalized), there's not difference between 'Y<enter', 'y<enter>', or just '<enter'